# Firefox adds extra space in Angular Material form field

Tags: css, angular, firefox, angular-material

I am using angular reactive forms. One of the form fields uses a datepicker and it looks like this in chrome. [image]

[image]

However, in firefox, it adds extra space to the top.
[image]
[image]

In order to fix it, I tried adding `bottom: 6px` to mat-form-field-infix in dev-tools (firefox) and it seemed to work. But the alignment in chrome gets wrong if I add the same attribute in chrome. Any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Firefox browser specific CSS.

There are two options to include in your CSS files

1. Using **@-moz-document url-prefix()**

   ```
        @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
            .mat-form-field-label-wrapper { 
                margin-top: -6px; 
            } 
        }
   ```
2. Using **@supports (-moz-appearance:none)**

   ```
    @supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
        .mat-form-field-label-wrapper { 
                margin-top: -6px; 
        } 
    }
   ```